# MKMapview Crashing on Initialization - Showing stranger error - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

I'm adding MKMapview in the code. Its crashing on initialization. Error is very stranger and I'm not getting why its happening.

I have added Mapkit Framework also.  here is the code

```
    NSString *lat = @"30.733315";
    NSString *lon = @" 76.779419";


    MKMapView   *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 205)];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.zoomEnabled=NO;
    mapView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    // [mapView setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.7326808, -73.9843407) animated:NO];
    mapView.scrollEnabled=NO;
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue], [lon floatValue]), 500, 500);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:NO];
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue], [lon floatValue]);
    annotation.title=@"qadsa";
    [mapView addAnnotation: annotation];
    [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Error I'm facing is :

```
2017-10-01 21:13:15.200959+0530 map[45012:6213684] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1860e3d38 0x1855f8528 0x18607cc44 0x186069e34 0x18bd11514 0x18bd10c28 0x18bd100ac 0x18bd11c8c 0x18bd11cb4 0x18bd84f28 0x18bd86a48 0x104c2545c 0x104c2617c 0x18bd86a18 0x18bf24350 0x104c375cc 0x104c2545c 0x104c34110 0x104c289a4 0x104c35104 0x104c3c100 0x185d0efe0 0x185d0ec30)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: your array have no element Array is empty..

Comment: @sagar which array :) 
This is simple mapview code. I have added this code in view did load. that's it. its crashing on very first line of MKMapview

Comment: Put the break point and debug your code.Now you can find out which line is crashing.

Comment: its crashing on Mkmapview line. I tried adding mapview in storyboard but it still crashes.

Comment: can you post the line where your app crash? @prateeksharma

Comment: Set an all exception breakpoint by clicking on the breakpoint tab, then clicking the plus button to add a new breakpoint. When the error occurs, the code will break exactly where it happened at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for checking the question and suggesting me answer.

It was due to Localization of string. I'm making multilingual Application. It was crashing for the wrong string in Localization file (Spanish). After i removed the localization , app start working. So I have rewrite whole Localization file again and bug fixed. Now Map is working fine.

So Error was due to localization of file. Major obstacle was Xcode don't show any error for localization file. it shows strange error.

Comment: The code you posted has no localisations at all, it would usually help others if you post what exactly was the problem and the steps you took to get it working. Thanks